# Mock controller action, set Request.InputStream as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to test a controller action that reads JSON from the Request.InputStream and outputs a dynamic. I don't understand what the Mock Request.InputStream type should be. I have tried it as a MemoryStream and passed it a byte array, but the it fails to read it.

My mock so far looks like this:

```
var str = "{ MediaItem: null, ParentId: 2897, Post: null, PostContent: hello }";
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
request.SetupGet(x => x.InputStream).Returns(stream);
request.Setup(x => x.InputStream).Returns(stream);
request.Setup(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost:35199/api/comment/create"));

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

CommentController controller = new CommentController(pr, ur, er, apr, ar);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

ActionResult expected = null;
ActionResult actual = controller.Create();
```

The JSON reader does this:

```
public static dynamic SqueezeJson(HttpRequestBase Request)
{        
    var bodyText = "";
    using (var stream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText)) return null;

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(bodyText, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
}
```

This throws this error:

> Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: a. Path '', line 1, position 6.

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned that I don't have the liberty of refactoring the controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Just pasted your Json string into a parser and it failed.  Have you tried changing it to a valid Json representation?

```
{ "MediaItem": "null", "ParentId": "2897", "Post": "null", "PostContent": "hello" }
```

Updated for your scenario:

```
var str = "{ \"MediaItem\": \"null\",\"ParentId\": \"2897\", \"Post\": \"null\", \"PostContent\": \"hello\" }";
```

HTH

Comment: how do I do that in c#? if i built it as a string in that form it still fails... i thought it would be new {MediaItem="null", ParentId="2897"} but that also fails because it has '=' instead of ':' (i presume)

Comment: you can use the escape sequence \" to add in the quotes, have updated my answer to show it

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your controller does too much work. Try to abstract the json reader in another class, and inject it in the controller. That way you will have 2 independent tests - one for the reader itself, and another one for the controller, that it just calls the reader, w/o actually having to think abouit how the reader works.

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
public interface IJsonReader
{
   dynamic SqueezeJson(Stream stream);
}

public class JsonReader : IJsonReader
{
   //implement SqeezeJson method
}

public class MyController
{
   private readonly IJsonReader _jsonReader;
   public MyController(IJsonReader jsonReader)
   {
      _jsonReader = jsonReader;
   }

   public ActionResult Create()
   {
       var data = _jsonReader.SqeezeJson(Context.Request.InputStream);
       //... do wahtever needed
   }
}

// ... and the tests

[Test]
public void SqueezeJsonTest()
{
   //test that the reader works as expected
}

public void ControllerTest()
{
   //arrange
   var requestStream = Mock.Of<Stream>();
   var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequestBase>( r => 
       r.InputStream == requestStream &&
       r.Url == "http://whatever");
   var context = Mock.Of<HttpRequestBase>(c=>c.Request == request);

   dynamic sqeezedData = new ExpandoObject(); // populate with the expected data from reader
   var mockReader = new Mock<IJsonReader>();
   mockReader.Setup(r=>r.SqeezeJson(requestStream)).Returns(sqeezedData); 

   var controller = new MyController();
   controller.Context = context;

   //act
   var result = controller.Create();

   //assert
   //whatever is needed to verify that the controller processed the sueezed data
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to refactor. Also, this doesn't help with the specific error I mentioned.